# How to embed id to a randomly generated text

Tags: java, c++, text, logic, text-parsing

I am trying to embed id to randomly generated text at the generator side. I would analyse the text and then parse it to get the id at the analyzer side.

I know if I use special characters, I am able to do this.
For example : @userid1 randomText @userId2 . Here I can use regular expression to extract userid1 and userid2.

Is there any other way to do this without using special characters?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by generator side, embed id and how randomly generated text is related to that. Can you clearify these? Maybe with code?

Comment: I generate random texts store it in array for example. After that access each text in the array and add two ids to each text and add it to next array.  That is my generator. 
Analyzer is just that reads each text from the array and extracts the id.

Comment: What are the ids used for? You wrap the random text in these just to remove them again? Aren't the array positions fixed when you pass the array to the Analyzer so you need to specify what the text is used for upon creation?